# Why is this program crashing if introduce more than one pair of data?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing program to introduce in a dynamically allocated array and later to print it. If I introduce only one set of values everything is fine but if I introduce more that 1 pair of values the program crashes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int *a, *b, m;
void askData(int **a, int **b);
void printData(int **a, int **b);

int main(){

    bool control = true;

    do{
        cout <<" ************* MENU ************* "<< endl;
        cout <<"    1.-  Ask for values  "<< endl;
        cout <<"    2.-  Print values  "<< endl;
        cout <<"    3.-  Exit "<< endl;

        cout << "Select one option: " << endl;
        int n;
        cin >> n;

        switch(n){
        case 1:
            askData(&a,&b);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            printData(&a,&b);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Exit" << endl;
            break;
        }

        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        if(n == 3){
            control = false;
        }
    }while(control);
    return 0;
}

void askData(int **a, int **b){
    cout << endl << "Enter the number of pairs of data: ";
    cin >> ::m;
    int z = ::m;

    *a = new int[z];
    *b = new int[z];

    for(int i=0; i<z; i++){
        cout << "Enter V[" << i <<"], Enter T[" << i << "]:?";
        cin >> *a[i] >> *b[i];
    }

    delete [] a;
    delete [] b;
}

void printData(int **a, int **b){
    for(int i=0; i < m; i++){
        cout << *a[i] << " " << *b[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The point of having parameters in a situation like this is that you don't need global variables.

Comment: beyond what other people said, there's another subtle bug. `*a[i]` means `*(a[i])` and not `(*a)[i]` which seems like the thing you actually wanted. edit: Nevermind, @tonga pointed that out before me

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to read the memory after freeing it(dangling pointer), which would have *undefined behaviour*.

Your function *askData* is allocating the memory and filling the data.But at the end of this function your are releasing the memory which was stored in global variable *a* & *b*

Now inside the *printData*() function, you are passing the freed memory pointer which you are tying to read. This causes problem.

**EDIT1**

We should avoid to use raw pointer instead of that use smart pointer provided by C++. In that case you would not have to worry about the manual memory management.

**EDIT2**

Your program is trying to write into *a* & *b*(which is pointer to pointer). Anyway for your program you can remove the argument passing to different function as they are global variable. But I suggest you to start using ***std::vector*** and ***smart_pointer***.

Read about how to use these concepts from the ISOCPP FAQ link:

http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#memory-leaks

```
void askData(){
    a = new int[z];
    b = new int[z];
    for(int i=0; i<z; i++){
        cout << "Enter V[" << i <<"], Enter T[" << i << "]:?";
        cin >> a[i] >> b[i];
    }
}

void printData(){
    for(int i=0; i < m; i++){
        cout << a[i] << " " << b[i] << endl;
    }
    delete [] a;
    delete [] b;
}
```

Comment: @Dulox1, Yes you need to remove this code from askData() and put into the printData() function as printData() would use this memory at the last.

Comment: @Dulox1: Basically you need to make sure that your program should not access the memory after freeing it. One more point is you have declared a & b as global variable in that case you do not require to pass it as an argument in the function. However we should avoid to use the global variable.

Comment: Ok, I just did what you said and remove the delete [] for ask data to print data but the program still crashes

Comment: a and b in printdata are int**, you need to dereference them before you delete them.  i.e. `delete [] *a;'

Answer (score 2):

When you create the dynamic array in the `askData` function, you need to dereference the array as:

```
for(int i=0; i<z; i++){
    cout << "Enter V[" << i <<"], Enter T[" << i << "]:?";
    cin >> (*a)[i] >> (*b)[i];
}
```

Same thing for the `printData` function, you need to dereference them as:

```
for(int i=0; i < m; i++){
    cout << (*a)[i] << " " << (*b)[i] << endl;
}
```

Note that when you use

```
*a = new int[z];
*b = new int[z];
```

`*a` and `*b` are pointers to an integer array of size `z`. And `a` and `b` are pointer to pointer as defined in the function argument list.

You also need to comment out those two lines as suggested by others

```
//delete [] a;
//delete [] b;
```

Don't forget to free up the memory at the end of `printData`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
delete [] a;
delete [] b;
```

removed the memory i.e the array is no longer allocated and data removed from the heap .

Comment: But i commented out delete [] a; and delete [] b; and problem still persist

Comment: @Dulox1 can you use a debugger and step by step move into the program  . it will tell you which data structure is corrupted and causing the crash .

Comment: Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5
Child process PID: 5044
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In std::istream::operator>>(int&) () ()
[Inferior 1 (process 5044) exited with code 030000000472]
Debugger finished with status 0

Comment: @Dulox1 which line was it ? I cant make it out from here .

Comment: a and b must be dereferenced.  `delete [] *a;`

Answer (score 0):

First I'd recomment you make your global variables local and initialize them.  It's easier to troubleshoot what's doing wrong.

```
int *a = 0, *b = 0, m;
```

To pull off the local variables you'll need to add a third parameter for `askData()` and `printData()` for the size of the array.

```
void askData(int **a, int **b, int &m);  // m is by reference because you want to return the size
void printData(int **a, int **b, int m);
```

The method `askData()` should check that `a` and `b` already point to memory, which should be freed before allocating more

```
    if( *a != 0 )  
    { 
        delete [] *a;   
    }
    *a = new int[m];

    if( *b != 0 ) 
    { 
        delete [] *b; 
    }
    *b = new int[m];
```

Since you're passing in `m`, you don't need to declare `z`.

```
    cout << endl << "Enter the number of pairs of data: ";
    cin >> m;  // Just use m

    ...

    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        cout << "Enter V[" << i <<"], Enter T[" << i << "]:?";
        cin >> (*a)[i] >> (*b)[i];
    }
```

Next your program allocates memory that you need to take care of.  That shouldn't happen in `askData()`, but after you know you won't need that memory anymore.  In your case, I'd recommend placing it near the end of `main()`.  You should check if they are `NULL`, aka `0`, before trying to delete them

```
if( a != 0 )
{
    delete [] a;   // No asterick because these are `int*`
}

if( b != 0 )
{
    delete [] b;
}
```

You're modified program looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void askData(int **a, int **b, int &m);
void printData(int **a, int **b, int m);

int main(){
    int *a = 0, *b = 0, m;  // These are now local, much better 
    bool control = true;

    do{
        cout <<" ************* MENU ************* "<< endl;
        cout <<"    1.-  Ask for values  "<< endl;
        cout <<"    2.-  Print values  "<< endl;
        cout <<"    3.-  Exit "<< endl;

        cout << "Select one option: " << endl;
        int n;
        cin >> n;

        switch(n){
        case 1:
            askData(&a,&b, m);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            printData(&a,&b, m);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Exit" << endl;
            break;
        }

        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        if(n == 3){
            control = false;
        }
    }while(control);

    if( a != 0 )
    {
        delete [] a; 
    }

    if( b != 0 )
    {
        delete [] b;
    }

    return 0;
}

void askData(int **a, int **b, int &m){

    cout << endl << "Enter the number of pairs of data: ";
    cin >> m;

    if( *a != 0 ) 
    { 
        delete [] *a; 
    }
    *a = new int[m];

    if( *b != 0 ) 
    { 
        delete [] *b; 
    }
    *b = new int[m];

    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        cout << "Enter V[" << i <<"], Enter T[" << i << "]:?";
        cin >> (*a)[i] >> (*b)[i];
    }
}

void printData(int **a, int **b, int m){

    for(int i=0; i < m; i++){
        cout << (*a)[i] << " " << (*b)[i] << endl;
    }
}
```